# C++ String variable problem ( _ZNSt7_cxx1112 ) could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++

I am just trying to make a simple string variable and c++ giving me dynamic link library error
I compile it with

g++ (file_name.cpp) -o (file_name)

And It's giving me this error prompt

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\Programs\Testing\String.exe(My
>   C file with full path)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string data;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the image:[image]

Comment: Please post the error message and the command(s), which create it, as plain text here.

Comment: You get these kind of issues when linking to the wrong dll file. Posting a link containing a similar issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386599/entry-point-not-found-error-on-running-c-exe-file-after-compiling-with-mingw

Comment: Thank you, Indranil -static-libstdc++ this command works but I already work with many string operations but they work perfectly so why I am getting this type of error now can you give me a permanent solution Instead of this command

Comment: the other way is to take the dll from the compiler directory and copy it to the .exe file, e.g. as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110895/10316011

Comment: You can easily get this from using the wrong language version when compiling; note the “cxx11” in the message.